# Ag-grid - Master / detail hide chevron icon when there is no detail data

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

In master/detail example, the expand/collapse icon is always present when setting `[masterDetail]=true`. However, my data sometimes does not have detail rows and I would like to hide the chevron in this situation. In my example, callRecords property would be present on the data but it would be null:

```
getDetailRowData: function(params) {
    params.successCallback(params.data.callRecords);
},
```

How can I not show the chevron on master grid when the data is null? Note: the example visible here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail-detail-grids/#detail-grid-options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This exact requirement is covered [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail-master-rows/#dynamic-master-rows) in docs.

Basically you implement `isRowMaster` -

```
this.isRowMaster = function(dataItem) {
  return dataItem ? dataItem.callRecords.length > 0 : false;
};
```

From docs -

> In specify which rows should expand, provide the grid callback
>   isRowMaster. The callback will be called once for each row. Return
>   true to allow expanding and false to disallow expanding for that row.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, for some reason I missed that part of the doc

Comment: @Pratik Bhat kindly also check my SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69272959/how-to-disable-row-group-expand-functionality-on-one-row

Comment: That "callRecords" is an interface or what ? when i try to implement .length isn't working.

Comment: @Saiprashanth - it is an example, a data field in question

Answer (score 0):

By adding Boolean value to `isRowMaster` in the gridOptions we can able to enable or disable the icon visibility

```
const gridOptions = {
    defaultColDef: {
        editable: false,
        filter: true,
        floatingFilter: true,
        floatingFilterComponentParams: { suppressFilterButton: false },
        resizable: true,
        sortable: true,
        suppressColumnsToolPanel: false,
        suppressMenu: true,
    },
    isRowMaster: dataItem => {
        return !(dataItem.Status === 'OFFLINE')
    }
}
```